# Modal causing double scroll Bar

Tags: html, css

Opening a modal on my site is causing a double scroll bar (both vertical) issue. The modal uses `position: fixed` and `overflow: auto`. I know it is `overflow: auto` causing the issue, but I need this style, as my modal contains a lot of content which in most cases could not fit in the users viewport, therefore scrolling the content is a requirement.

```
.enquire-nav {
    font-family: inherit;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(36, 32, 33, .97);
}
```

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: Please show your relevant code.

Comment: @Drown Added the relevant CSS. I'm sure of the fact my markup is not causing the issue.

Comment: *"I know it is overflow: auto causing the issue"* ...well there you are. Seems to me you'll have to rethink here.

Comment: @Paulie_D As I mentioned, "scrolling the content is a requirement".

Comment: ...and this is the issue. It's working exactly as it's supposed to. I'm interested to see if this actually **has** a solution...but i doubt it as it stands. Perhaps another inner wrapper for the content that can move about *inside* your modal?

Comment: @Paulie_D This one really has me stumped, I'll let you know if I find a solution though. I would just place the content on a new page, but unfortunately I need to display it as a modal.

Comment: I obviously understand why this would add a vertical scroll bar, but not two of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the end I found that the best solution was to toggle a class on the body when the modal is opened, this class would add `overflow-y: hidden`. This allows me to scroll the content of the modal if it overflows the body, but doesn't allow scrolling of the body itself at the same time. No more double scroll bars.

The jQuery:

```
  $(".menu-trigger, .primary-nav-item, .hamburger-one").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
    $('body').toggleClass("no-scroll");

  });
```

The CSS:

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've solved this issue before while building out my own jQuery modal plugin. Here's a link to the github repo, for reference: https://github.com/thecox/bw-box. I'll dig around and find some of the relevant styling that resolved the issue. Here's the main structure:

**HTML**

```
<div id="default-modal" class="bwbox__modal">
  <div class="bwbox__modal__outer">
    <div class="bwbox__modal__middle">
      <div class="bwbox__modal__inner">
        <a href="#" class="bwbox__modal__inner__close">CLOSE X</a>
        <div class="bwbox__modal__inner__content">
          <!-- Content Goes Here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bwbox__modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.bwbox__modal__outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bwbox__modal__middle {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bwbox__modal__inner {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  color: #555;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 885px;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 2em 2% 1em;
  margin: 30px auto;

.bwbox__modal__inner__content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  text-align: center;
}

.bwbox__modal__inner__close {
  position: absolute;
  color: #555;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Basically, the outer, middle, and inner containers center the container vertically and horizontally in the frame in such a way that if they expand beyond the window height, you can still scroll. Maybe pull it down and check out the demo.Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm away at the moment, but I'll let you know if it fixes the issue when I'm back. Thank you for your answer :]

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, similar to Leon Burman's answer:

```
  setBodyModalHidden(isHidden: boolean) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).style.overflowY = isHidden ? 'hidden' : '';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modern CSS-only solution (no JS required).**

Remove scrollbar from `<html>` if it contains a CSS selector that indicates the modal is active:

```
html:has(.modal-active) {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

The solution uses `:has` which is [supported by all browsers except Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Until Firefox supports `:has`, just hide main scrollbar while still allowing scrolling:

```
/* First: hide scrollbar while still allowing scrolling. */    

html {
    scrollbar-width: none;
}


/* Then re-enable the scrollbar for browsers that support :has */

@supports selector(body:has(.modal-active)) {
    html {
        scrollbar-width: initial;
    }
}
```

I used this to remove the double scrollbars from a textarea that switches to a fullscreen modal when it is focused without any JS.